# SAPUi5 Radio Button Selected Text

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a radio button in my XMLview as shown below. The data is bound from the model. My requirement is to validate the radio buttons after the data binding. Below is my controller code. i am trying to read the value of the selectedButton text in my controllers AfterRendering method.

XML View:

```
<RadioButtonGroup id="rbgtype" > 
<RadioButton text="Yes" selected="{/rbgtype}"/> 
<RadioButton text="No" selected="{=!${/rbgtype}}"/> </RadioButtonGroup>
```

Controller

```
onAfterRendering: function () { 
var that = this; console.log("rbgtype"+that.getView().byId("rbgtype").getSelectedButton().getText());}
```

Strangely I am always getting the value "Yes" , irrespective of selected value. Can some one advise where I am doing wrong please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does that because the RadioButtonGroup doesn't initially have a property set `selectedIndex`. It seems to fail the `getSelectedButton` method whenever `selectedIndex` isn't set.

Maybe you can work around this issue like this? Hope this helps.

**View**

```
        <RadioButtonGroup id="rbgtype" selectedIndex ="{/rbgtype}">
            <RadioButton text="Yes" />
            <RadioButton text="No"/>
        </RadioButtonGroup>
```

**Controller**

```
        onInit: function() {
        var type = false;
        var oModel = new JSONModel({
            rbgtype: type ? 0 : 1
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },

    onAfterRendering: function() {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("rbgtype: " + this.byId("rbgtype").getSelectedButton().getText());
    },
```

**VIEW 2**

```
<RadioButtonGroup id="rbgtype" selectedIndex ="{= ${rbgtype} ? 0 : 1 }">
            <RadioButton text="Yes" />
            <RadioButton text="No"/>
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

Comment: Hi Matthijs I have an issue. Please can you guide me in the right direction? I've a base64 string for msword doc and I need to display in UI5 is it possible?

Comment: I can download it but I don't want to download it, Just display it. Created Link below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292332/display-base64-word-string-in-popup-using-sapui5

Comment: HI Matthijs, I have applied the code , however when I add this piece in onInit I am loosing my existing model data. the data is being displayed already however not able to read the binded value.

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
   rbgtype: type ? 0 : 1
  });

  this.getView().setModel(oModel);

Comment: What does your model look like? And how do you load it?

Comment: It is an extension and I have replaced the view.  <RadioButtonGroup id="rbgTermType" selectedIndex ="{/rbgtype}">
    <RadioButton text="Yes" selected="{/rbgtype}" />
    <RadioButton text="No" selected="{=!${/rbgtype}}"/>
   </RadioButtonGroup>

I have added the SelectedINdex and getting this below error ____
Uncaught Error: "true" is of type boolean, expected int for property "selectedIndex" of Element

Comment: Remove your radiobuttongroup and replace it by the one in my answer (VIEW 2) and tell me what happens.

Comment: @MatthijsMennens View2 code is working fine.will be doing more tests and will close the thread. appreciate your time and help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your xml view radionbuttongroup aggregation and binding

```
<RadioButtonGroup id="rbgtype" >
                <buttons>


<RadioButton text="Yes" selected="{/rbgtype}"/> 
<RadioButton text="No" selected="{=!${/rbgtype}}"/> </RadioButtonGroup>
                </buttons>
            </RadioButtonGroup>
```

Once you fix it then you can add an event delegate for onAfterRendering in onInit function of the controller

see example below

```
var rbGrp= this.getView().byId("rbgtype");

rbGrp.addEventDelegate({

onAfterRendering:function(){/*write your code here*/}                                                        

      }, this);
```

Hope this helps. Any issues let me know

Comment: thank you! I have addeed the addEventDelegate in onInit nad  please see my code . rbGrp.addEventDelegate({

onAfterRendering:function(){console.log("ivnvnvnvnvbnbvnvn"+rbGrp.getSelectedButton().getText());}                                                        

      }, this);
however still the same error, I need to read the binded value.

Comment: When the property selectedIndex isn't set for the RBG, you won't be able to get the correct selected button.